# WooCommerce Coupon - Hide 0 amount value for total order section and only show on recurring

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We use WooCommerce Subscription and created a recurring coupon. This means on the initial order, there is no discount. Only on the recurring orders. By default WooCommerce displays on the checkout, after adding this coupon, two times the coupon information. One position is shown with the discount value of $0 for to total order and at one position the coupon code amount is shown for the recurring orders.

Screenshot: https://ibb.co/9yKK92X (Checkout page)

This looks strange because this is a coupon only for recurring orders. So it should be shown only on the recurring order section. I tried to hide the coupon in the total order section with the code below. But it does not work as expected. Also I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing it.

Does someone know how we can do that?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 10, 5 ); // add filter for all coupons
function filter_woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount( $discount, $discounting_amount, 
$cart_item, $single, $coupon ) { 
// filter the discount if coupon amount is 0
if($discount == 0 && $cart_item['line_subtotal'] == $cart_item['line_total']){ 
    echo "<script>document.querySelector('.cart-discount').style.display = 'none';</script>";
}
    
return $discount;
}
```

Comment: Your screenshot is from which page? order details page, cart page, checkout page, or something else?

Comment: Its from checkout page

Comment: And you've manually applied the coupon code or it's auto-applied from your custom code?

Comment: manually. The customer will add this code

Answer (score 2):

why not just use CSS to hide it?

you can simply target the cart-discount excluding the recurring discount

e.g.

```
.cart-discount:not(.recurring-total) {
    diplay: none ;
}
```

or use the first 1 or 2 characters from your coupon as wildcard css selector to target specific coupon and hide it.

assuming your coupon is `nananana` you can use the first 2 characters like so;

```
tr[class^="coupon-na"]:not(.recurring-total), tr[class*=" coupon-na"]:not(.recurring-total) {
    display: none;
}
```

if simple css won't work, then your only option is to edit woocommerce template files namely the following

```
/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-totals.php
/woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php
```

look for the lines where it loops on the coupon, something like

```
<?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
    <tr class="cart-discount...">
    .
    .
    .
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

then add a condition where it only display if discount amount is greater than `0`, something like this should do,

```
<?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
    <?php 
        $totalDiscount = WC()->cart->get_coupon_discount_amount( $coupon->get_code(), WC()->cart->display_cart_ex_tax );
        if ( $totalDiscount > 0 ) {
    ?>
        <tr class="cart-discount...">
        .
        .
        .
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**EDIT**

You can actually do some jquery hacks, although it can have delay on hiding the coupon item, in the example below, I use `MutationObserver` to listen for any changes inside `.shop_table` div, and set a delay as woocommerce also modify the DOM when you add/remove a coupon. so the code only runs 50ms after woocommerce do something DOM changes

```
( function($) {

    let delay, // set a timer delay
        origOrder = $('.shop_table') //get original shop_table div

    if ( origOrder.length > 0 ) {
        new MutationObserver(() => {
            if (delay) clearTimeout(delay) // reset timer delay
            delay = setTimeout(() => {
                const order = $('.shop_table')
                if ( origOrder !== order) { // check for any shop_table div changes
                    origOrder = order
                    hideZeroCoupon()
                }
            }, 50) // run 50ms after DOM modified

        }).observe(document, {subtree: true, childList: true})
    }

    function hideZeroCoupon() {
        
        const orderCoupon = $('.cart-discount').not('.recurring-total')
        
        orderCoupon.each( (key, item) => {

            const orderCouponAmount = $(item).find('.amount')
            
            if ( orderCouponAmount.length > 0 ) {
                const discount = parseFloat( orderCouponAmount.text().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') )
                if ( discount === 0 ) {
                    $(item).hide()
                }
            }
        })
        
        
    }
    
})(jQuery);
```